# images created with Symfony and Twig sometimes display wrong

Tags: image, twig, symfony

I have some images created with Symfony, they are generated as:

```
src="data:image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...  etc"
data-holder-rendered="true"
```

With this code in my controller:

```
$sql = "select id,nombre,descripcion,encode(imagen, 'base64') as imagen from data.servicios_mapa order by destacado DESC, fecha_creacion DESC LIMIT 4" ;
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
$mapas = $stmt->fetchAll();
$datos_mapa = array();
foreach($mapas as $m){
     if($m['imagen'] != '' || $m['imagen'] != null){
         $m['imagen'] = "data:image;base64,".$m['imagen'];
     }else{
         $m['imagen'] = "/imgs/no-image.jpg";
     }
     $datos_mapa[] = $m;
 }

 return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array("estructura"=>json_encode(array()),"datosmapas"=>$datos_mapa) );
```

Then in Twig:

```
<img src="{{ mapa.imagen }}"  class="img-responsive fix-height">
```

But some of them are wrongly diplayed, like the left one:

http://fotos.subefotos.com/5909f04a9cfa9be2c4b286d1b87727eco.png

What could be the reasson? they are all generated with the same code.

Comment: This is probably not because of Symfony or Twig but rather your images are malformed already.

Comment: I don't know how. The images are stored in the DB as "bytea" type, why some images are chuncked and other don't...

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, the else for the condition `if($m['imagen'] != '' || $m['imagen'] != null)` is never reached when `$m['imagen'] == null` or `$m['imagen'] == ''`

because null != '' gives true, and '' != null gives true

So you will have `<img src="data:image;base64,"  class="img-responsive fix-height">`

You should change it to : `if($m['imagen'] != '' && $m['imagen'] != null)`

Comment: It doesn't change anything, the images are still the same (someones are ok generated someones not)

Comment: Maybe it comes from the images stored in the DB. Have you tried rendering the images in a static HTML page ?

Comment: Someone of my team has fixed the problem. It was the way that the images were insert in the DB, they were croped before encoding, and that croping were messing the file.